# using eval on imported function / way around

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, eval

I want to use this function :

```js
eval("TableRowName({row:row , openDetail:openInfo , resolveCompNum:resolveCompNum , skipParams:skipParams , paramNameMap:paramNameMap , })")
```

but `TableRowName` is imported function. Is there way to go around this ?